# Exec() not working in python3 with running .py code

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am trying to have python pull each row of the database into its own button and then run the code contained within that blob when the button is clicked.

The exec function is not executing the code pulled from the database, it successfully prints everytime as I added this to assist with debugging but never actually runs the code contained within the blob.

Problem code:

```
def run_file(fName):
            connectiondb = mysql.connector.connect(user='admin', password='admin', host='localhost', database='cypilearning')
            cursordb = connectiondb.cursor()
            cursordb.execute("SELECT filedata FROM cyberphysicalsystems WHERE name = %s", [(fName)])
            r = cursordb.fetchall()
            for i in r:
                data = i[0]
            decodedData = data.decode("utf8")
            tk.messagebox.showinfo(fName, decodedData)
            exec(decodedData)
            connectiondb.commit()
            connectiondb.close()

        def check_files():
            connectiondb = mysql.connector.connect(user='admin', password='admin', host='localhost', database='cypilearning')
            cursordb = connectiondb.cursor()
            cursordb.execute("SELECT name FROM cyberphysicalsystems")
            r = cursordb.fetchall()
            startX = 25
            startY = 275
            j = 0
            for i in r:
                button = Button(self, text=i, width=15)
                button.configure(bg="#83B4B3", activebackground="#097392", command=lambda i=i: run_file(i[0]))
                button.place(x=startX, y=startY)
                startX = startX+200
                j = j+1
                if j == 6:
                    startY = startY+100
                    startX = 25
                    j = 0
            connectiondb.commit()
            connectiondb.close()
```

Comment: Why do you wish to use exec? What's the error with traceback? Doesn't print the correct thing?

Comment: I want to use exec as I am creating an application to run mini activities to be used in school outreach programs. There is no error showing at all, it just doesn't run any code string within exec, whether it be simple maths string or if its a more complicated tkinter gui game.

Comment: Try using `eval()` instead